# How can I fetch records whose column is not 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to add scope, in which all the records whose `sign_in_count` column is not `0`

How can I?

```
scope :confirmed, where("sign_in_count" => 0)
```

This probably fetches all the records whose `sign_in_count` is 0.

I want opposite. How can I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scope :confirmed, where("sign_in_count <> 0 ")
```

Comment: which is better? yours or `scope :confirmed, where("sign_in_count != ?",0)`

Comment: @HUSTEN '<>' is SQL-92 standard.  So maybe a bit more portable than '!='.  Also, '<> 0' won't return rows where sign_in_count is null. So keep that in mind.

Comment: depends what DB you use. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp And imho NULL value could also cause an issue, i would go with "> 0" to be sure